# Get pairwise iterator with additional item in the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, python-itertools

The goal: e.g. given finite iterator `p0, p1, ..., pn` turn into `(p0, p1), (p1, p2), ..., (pn-1, pn), (pn, None)` — iterator through pairs of consecutive items with special last item.

`pairwise()` function exists in the documentation as example of `itertools` usage:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

But  I want additionally add yet another item to the end of iterator (if it is finite) with some default value for the second element of pair (e.g., `None`).

How to efficiently implement this additional functionality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip_longest(a, b)
```

When one of the input iterators runs out, `zip_longest` pads it with a filler value, which defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

As for adding `(sn, None)` at the end, as user2357112 already answered, you can just use `zip_longest` so one already exhausted iterator is not stopping the whole sequence (so the `a` iterator can still yield the last element).

For all other situations, e.g. if you want to add further elements at the end, you can just make a generator function itself. All the `itertools` function are already lazy generators, only producing new results when you request the next element in the result, and you can easily consume those from within a generator.

Let’s say, you need `pairwise` to yield a sentinel value `(None, None)` at the end, then you could simply yield the results from `zip_longest` and then yield another item:

```
def example (iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    yield from zip_longest(a, b)
    yield (None, None)
```

The `yield from` syntax actually came with Python 3.3. For earlier versions, especially Python 2, you would need to do that manually by looping over the items and yielding them again:

```
def example (iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    for x in zip_longest(a, b):
        yield x
    yield (None, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generator:

```
def pairwise(iterable, additional=None):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    first, second = next(iterable), next(iterable)
    while 1:
        yield first,second
        try:
            first,second = second, next(iterable)
        except TypeError:
            yield second, additional
            break
```

Results:

```
>>> list(pairwise([1,2,3], 'a'))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 'a')]
>>> list(pairwise('abc', 'a'))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a')]
>>> list(pairwise('abcd', 'a'))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a')]
```

For an infinite iterable:

```
>>> a = pairwise(infi(), 6)
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(next(a))
...
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
```